# Magento223: How to Import CSV during module installation

Tags: magento2, import, csv

I have **custom module** in which i am **importing csv file** upon **button click**.
I want to **import the csv during module installation**, i don't know how to implement it in install data file.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can find examples of import CSV files during installation on Magento 2 Sample data module https://github.com/magento/magento2-sample-data/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/CatalogSampleData/Setup/Installer.php